# File in the remote is not getting deleted

Tags: git, jenkins

i've deleted a file in my local and pushed the application code to the repository, via git extension. And have pulled the code from the repository to another remote machine, via jenkins using git plugin. But the  particular file which i've deleted in my local is still available in the remote machine even after the pull. At the same time it has been deleted in repository also.

On surfing, i can find enough info for deleting a file and pushing it. but not by pull.

why is it happening?? what i need to do to delete the file in remote machine??

Git Extension version : 2.48
Jenkins version : 2.46.3

Comment: Probably you didn't activate the option "Delete workspace before build starts" under "Build environment" in the project configuration.

Comment: thanks bro.. will try and let you know!!

Answer (score 0):

In build configuration please enable "Delete workspace before build starts"  and try to rebuild the job. Now the file which you removed from local and removed will not get pulled to your jenkins repo.

[image]